# HTTPClient and parsing out header values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httpclient

I'm using HTTPClient for the first time and making requests like the following:

```
r=c.get('http://slashdot.org')
tmp={}
tmp[:location_id]=x.id
tmp[:body]=r.body
tmp[:last_modified]=r.header['Last-Modified']
tmp[:content_length]=r.header['Content-Length']
puts "last modified: " + r.header['Last-Modified'].to_s
# last modified: ["Fri, 12 Aug 2011 19:26:24 GMT"]
puts "content-length: " + r.header['Content-Length'].to_s
# content-length: ["2138"]
puts tmp['location_id']
Crawl.create(tmp)
```

Is there a better way for accessing variable like Last-Modified than `r.header['Last-Modified']` which returns `["Tue, 18 Oct 2011 00:33:15 GMT"]` ?

thx

---

Take out the brackets and quotes. I'd rather it just output:

```
Tue, 18 Oct 2011 00:33:15 GMT
```

rather than

```
["Tue, 18 Oct 2011 00:33:15 GMT"]
```

I'm figuring I'm probably doing something wrong.

thx

Comment: It would be helpful if you show us the class (or a simplified version at least).

Answer (score 0):

The "`[...]`" means that the object you get from `r.header['Last-Modified']` is an Array.  HTTPClient#get returns [HTTP::Message](http://rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient/2.2.4/HTTP/Message) object.  And [HTTP::Message#header[]](http://rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient/2.2.4/HTTP/Message/Headers#%5B%5D-instance_method) returns an Array for the given key ('Last-Modified' this time.).

You can just pick the first String from the Array; `r.header['Last-Modified'].first`

There's another way, you can get a Hash object of the given response header by calling `r.headers`. [HTTP::Message#headers](http://rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient/2.2.4/HTTP/Message#headers-instance_method) does picking the first value instead of you so `r.headers['Last-Modified']` should work.

The reason HTTP::Message#header[] returns an Array is HTTP response header could have multiple keys in a single response.